# how to move files from onedrive back to your laptop?

Tags: dropbox, onedrive

how to move files from onedrive back to your laptop?

i didn't know dropbox could autosync so i made the mistake of setting up onedrive

i can't believe i even need to be asking this. took 4 hours to look for an answer......

i also want to know the exact steps (in bullet point) you used to find the answer

Comment: First off, what OS are you using and how are you accessing OneDrive? Second, did you select what you want and click "Download"? What does Dropbox have to do with your question?

Comment: FWIW, I didn't down vote this question. You earned those all by yourself.

Comment: It seems as you came here with something to prove. Sorry you feel you are having such a hard time. It may be less frustrating if you follow the guidelines thousands of others use. BTW, the community voted to put this question on hold, not some arbitrary moderator action. All this hate from you simply because I asked you to clarify your question. Good luck to you.

Comment: @ambw - There isn't a single moderator that voted to close your question.  All 5 people who voted to close your question are normal users.  They have no special powers, based on the fact, it took 5 users to close your question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First things first: You should be using Dropbox. Just my opinion, but a strong one.

Presumably at this point, you have files in OneDrive, but not on your computer. You probably have OneDrive installed already, but in case you don't:

1. Install [OneDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-us/download/).
2. Sign into OneDrive with your Microsoft ID
3. It will make you click through a couple of basic prompts, but you will eventually be brought to the *Sync Only What You Want* window. Select *All Files and Folders In My OneDrive*.
4. It will ask you about *Fetch Your Files From Anywhere* which you can use at your discretion.
5. OneDrive should automatically begin setting up a local copy of whatever you have in the cloud. This may take a while if you have a lot of data up there.
6. Profit.

Comment: The dig about switching to Dropbox really wasn't necessary. Just my opinion, but a strong one.